# TFS XAML Build that runs tests failing after Windows Updates

Tags: xaml, tfs, build, msbuild

We recently applied Windows Updates to our TFS build servers, and the day after we started seeing this error when running any xaml build that is supposed to run unit/UI tests:

Exception Message: Team Foundation Server could not load the following test settings: QAChromeConfig. (type ArgumentException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Workflow.Activities.ExecuteRemoteTestRun2.TestRunCreation.GetRunConfiguration(ITestSettings testSettings)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Workflow.Activities.ExecuteRemoteTestRun2.TestRunCreation.CreateTestRun(CodeActivityContext context, ITestManagementService testManager, ITestManagementTeamProject project)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: When you say Windows updates, do you mean just a patch, or you update the windows version such as from windows 8 to windows 10？ And did this only influence the test part? What' the result of normal XAML build?

Comment: Just security updates and such. I don't have the list from IT. And yes it only affected the builds that run tests

Comment: It's hard to trouble shooting this kind of issue without detail update info. Do your have any other build agent/server with the same windows update for test, this will narrow down if the issue is related to windows update patch or not. If so, you could submit a bug  to Developer Community site(https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).